# Issue in PHP/MySQL query, but no error?

Tags: php, mysqli

Here's my code - I know the database connection is working and fine. The problem is the insert statement doesn't work - although the page finishes with no error...in fact, even if I purposely mis-spell the table name, it finishes with no error...? What gives?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'uname', 'upass', 'dbname');
mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO calendars (calnum,stamp) VALUES('555','678655')");
mysqli_close($db);

echo "Done";
?>
```

Comment: What does `mysqli_error($db)` say?

Comment: Try just `VALUES(555,678655)` without the quotes. I can't see what else it could be, unless you have an AUTO_INCREMENT column. And by the looks of this, you may have your columns not properly set. Show us your db schema. Not going to guess till the cows come home.

Comment: Was it the `'`? @Fred-ii-

Comment: I can't see how "adding" error reporting (accepted answer below) could possibly and `"magically"` enter values in DB. My money's on the quotes and/or wrong column type(s) @dollarvar - and to answer your question, ask the OP ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, I tried to magically ask the OP and inform you about me asking, the same time, haha. However I cannot think of any other cause either. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just show yours errors:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'uname', 'upass', 'dbname');
mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO calendars (calnum,stamp) VALUES('555','678655')") or die(mysqli_error($db));
mysqli_close($db);

echo "Done";
```

Comment: you are my hero! Thank you!

Comment: Always throw errors in your code and your life will be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a space after `VALUES`:

```
mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO calendars (calnum,stamp) VALUES ('555','678655')");
```

Comment: Nope - that's not it.

Comment: That would have wondered me too if that would have worked. ;)

Comment: Ah. I was just wondering if, like `VALUES()`, it took VALUES to be a function rather than a keyword. Oh well :P